# Microsoft Graph API - CalendarView Delete Event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to delete/cancel and event pulled from the CalendarView API for a given Conference Room. I have the Event ID and am trying the following:

```
graphClient.Users["conferenceroom@tenant.com"]
   .CalendarView[eventId]
   .Request(options)
   .DeleteAsync()
```

Receiving the following error message:

```
Message: The OData request is not supported.
```

Is it not possible to delete/cancel associated from a `CalendarView`?

I've noticed when I create the event (under my user) it has a different `ID` than if I pull the same `event` from the `CalendarView`.

Thoughts? When pulling the `CalendarView` for each Conference Room I wouldn't have context to the organizers `Events`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Code Sample:

```
            var query = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Option>()
                 {
                  new Microsoft.Graph.QueryOption("$filter", $"iCalUId eq '{eventId}'")
                 };

            var events = await graphClient.Users[User.Identity.Name].Events.Request(query).GetAsync();

            var evt = events.First();

            await graphClient.Users[User.Identity.Name].Events[evt.Id].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, what do you think might be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To delete an event you need to use the `/events` segment, not `/calendarview`. You can get the ID from the calendar view, then just do:

```
graphClient.Users[""].Events[eventId].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: What I'm seeing is when I create the event I include both myself and the conference room email as attendees. I get one event ID. Then when I pull the Calendar View Event for that conference room, it's a different ID.

Comment: I'm creating the Event under my email, not the conference room email.

Comment: The `id` for an event can change.  If you're looking for a unique identifier you can store, you should use the `iCalUId` property instead of `id`. Note that you cannot deleted based on `iCalUid` but you can quickly look up an Event's `id` using `/events?$filter=iCalUId eq '{value}'`

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thanks! How would I filter using the .NET Graph wrapper? I've tried this but not sure I'm there: .Events.Request().Expand($"singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=iCalUId eq '{eventId}')").GetAsync()

Comment: `iCalUid` isn't an extended property. You can would filter using `Events.Request().Filter("iCalUid eq '{iCalUid}').GetAsync()`

Comment: Don't have a .Filter property on the Request object. See above for my solution. Thank you!

Comment: To add to Marc's reply, the `id` is expected to be different between calendars. Basically you create the event on your own calendar and it gets a unique ID. A meeting request is sent to the conference room, which causes an event to be created on the conf room's calendar, which gets it's own unique ID. The `iCalUID` is stamped on both your event and the meeting request, so that when the event is created on the conf room's calendar, it gets the same value.